# Workflow Email Alerts Not Log In Email Related list of Case

Tags: workflow, case, email2case, email-alert

**Scenario**: Whenever the case is created one workflow will fire and it will sent an `email alert to the contact email of case`. This is sending email to contact email as per designed but it is `not logging in Email related list of case`.

Any reason why it is not logging in email related list.

Email `template contains "case thread Id" of case in subject and body` as well, but it is `still not logging in the case email related list`.

Is this the functionality salesforce missed or we can get the log in email related list?

Any thoughts?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently missing functionality from salesforce. there is currently an idea on the success.salesforce.com site for this - [Salesforce Success](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BroKAAS)

The work around that we use here is to make sure you CC in your email to case email to get a copy into salesforce.

Comment: The link which you posted is not a valid link. It will be helpful if you post correct link

Comment: Link is now correct.

Comment: How we can add cc in email alert?

Comment: In the edit screen for an email alert there is a box titled "Additional Email" you can enter the email to case email in this box.

Comment: This is great idea. This works fine. Any disadvantage if we use like this?

Comment: The disadvantage is it will create new case in salesforce.

Comment: What happens currently if someone replies back to an email your send from your cases? does it create a new case or does it assign the email to the case?

Comment: is this issue fixed and how?

Answer (score 1):

I use this work around. As long as the thread id is in the email it will not create a new case and responses will link back to the original case. The only downside I have experienced is that you can not get accurate report on Emails sent per Agent. By cc'ing the email-to-case email you get the email attached to the case but it is recorded as an incoming email, so you have no record of who actually sent it.

Comment: link not provided update please